# how to write npm script to copy directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to write npm script to copy entire directory to another directory.
I tried single file work(cp) , list directory work (dir), but copy directory does not work(cpdir)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@1.0.1 cpdir: `copy --r dist  distnew1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

```
  "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "cp" : "copy  test.txt  test1.txt",
        "dir" : "dir dist"
        "cpdir" : "copy  -r dist  distnew"

    },
```

Answer (score 11):

On a *-nix system the copy command is `cp`, so just use that.

```
"cpdir" : "cp -r ./dist  ./distnew"
```

Comment: this is window system.  copy  -r dist  distnew is work by themself

Answer (score 10):

You can also create operation system agnostic script to copy directory (or files):

1. `npm install --save-dev copyfiles` to install `copyfiles` package as your development dependency
2. in your `package.json` `"cpdir": "npx copyfiles soruceDir destinationDir"` - using `npx` you can execute your npm package binaries.
3. finally you run the copy script: `npm run cpdir`

This way, you don't have to worry about the OS that will run your npm script.